# Rails testing with active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, activeadmin

I'm using rails' build in tests as well as active admin. In most of my tests (the ones for which you need to log in in the actual software), I am getting the error that instead of performing whatever the test should do, it is getting a redirect to the login page (because as the test you are not logged in). How can I either log in as the admin user before testing, or ignore the necessity to log in for my tests?

to be clear, here is the result from one such test:

```
Failure:
PaymentsControllerTest#test_should_get_new [/home/silvertail/Documents/rails/bridal/test/controllers/payments_controller_test.rb:16]:
Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://www.example.com/admin/login>
```

I'm looking for something like:`current_admin_user = admin_users(:one)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to login an admin user into your test environment. Your could do something like this:

```
test "should get new" do

  user = users(:one)
  # The user :one should be defined in your users.yml and flagged as admin

  get login_path
  post login_path, params: { session: { email: user.email,
                                      password: user.password} }
  assert_response :success

end
```

I hope this helps.